# How to delete all the related records in table using MySql

Tags: php, mysql

The following is my table:

```
pk_parent_id       fk_parent_id    fk_user_id    timestamp
1                  NULL                32            2018-01-07 18:42:03
2                  1                   42            2018-01-07 18:42:17
3                  2                   57            2018-01-07 18:42:23   
4                  3                   74            2018-01-07 18:42:47    
5                  4                   93            2018-01-07 18:43:09
```

In the above table, `fk_parent_id` has the value of its parent record. i.e. `fk_parent_id = 3` means the record where `pk_parent_id = 3` is parent of this record.

I want to delete all the child rows if the parent row is deleted. 
i.e. if I delete the row where `pk_parent_id` is `4` then its child where `fk_parent_id = 4` must be deleted ( record 5).

if I delete the row where pk_parent_id is 3 then record 3,4, and 5 must be deleted ( 4 is the child of 3 and 5 is the child of 4).

I want to know whether this is possible in MySql query, if so then how. Or is there some other way I can proceed with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've actually configured them as foreign keys, you can just set the `ON DELETE CASCADE` flag and it'll happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a delete trigger on the table which will nest a nested chain of deletes:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbl AFTER DELETE on tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM tbl
    WHERE tbl.fk_parent_id = old.pk_parent_id;
END
```

old is the data that is deleted.  you will replace tbl with your table name.

Comment: had it backwards, changed it